# Properties for Sending email via gmail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm currently inline of writing a simple program to send email via gmail to a gmail account.
Have tried various ways but often i'm ending up on the same error, "Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;"

Whether it has got anything to do with properties settings. Here is the snippet from my program. Looking for a solution :)

Thanks in advance

```
public static boolean SendMail(String from, String password, String message, String to[]){
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        Properties prop = System.getProperties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        prop.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        prop.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", 587); //prop.put("mail.smtp.port", 465);//
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

         // check for the first value in the name of props or prop
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, null);
        MimeMessage mimemsg = new MimeMessage(session);

        try{
            mimemsg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            // Get reciepents Address
            InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];
            for (int i=0;i<to.length;i++){
                toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
            }

            //Add all toAddress to mimemessage
            for(int j=0;j<toAddress.length;j++){
                mimemsg.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, toAddress[j]);

            }

            // Add Subject.
            mimemsg.setSubject(" MAIL from JAVA Program");
            // Add Message to the content(input to the method )
            mimemsg.setText(message);

            Transport trans = session.getTransport("smtp");
            trans.connect(host,from,password);
            trans.sendMessage(mimemsg, mimemsg.getAllRecipients());
            trans.close();
            return true;

        }catch(MessagingException me){
            me.printStackTrace();
        }


    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you tried Port : 465?

Comment: @Senthilmurugan yes i've tried 465 also

Comment: Settings seem correct to me. GMail smtp is 587 for TLS (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en). Could it be your login details? Can you `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` from the same box and get the smtp greeting?

Comment: @alkar i'm not getting response for the telnet smtp.gmail.com 587

Comment: I found http://mandrillapp.com a couple month ago. For most tasks the email sending limits are amazingly high and you can use their API to easily send mails (https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/). It is so much easier than to use SMTP stuff.

Comment: @Vidhee I am getting a response. Therefore I assume it's a network issue :)

Comment: @alkar can you kindly share few destination IPs of Gmail

Comment: @Vidhee Pinging `smtp.gmail.com` gives me `173.194.78.108`. If you add this in your `hosts` file, does it work?

Comment: @alkar Thanks a lot for your reply. :)

Are you telling me to add the ip 173.194.78.108 in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts  ? Kindly help

Comment: @Vidhee either that or just use the IP address directly in your code to see if it works

Comment: @alkar Got the Code Working :) Feeling happy.
The Problem was with the network and it worked when i tried with 173.194.78.108

Comment: @Vidhee I've added an answer for you since it was that after all. Be careful though, you should fix that issue instead of using an IP address directly. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your settings seem correct. GMail SMTP port is [587](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en) for TLS. This looks like a network connectivity issue (the hostname does not resolve).

- Double check your login credentials.
- Try to `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` from the same box. Are you getting the SMTP greeting?
- Try to directly use an IP address. **Caution: you should not use a direct IP except for troubleshooting. It is bound to change at any time and render your code useless.**

Answer (score 0):

use this, `from` and `password` for Authentication and `props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");` `465` port number

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(from,password);
                }
            });
```

also use this property:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
```

Comment: @ MohsinAzeem. I did the suggested changes but still the error persists

Comment: see my recently changes

Comment: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: are you suggesting the addition of sslsocketfactory ? I've done that

Comment: can you post host name (input by user)?

Comment: I'm not getting the input from user. I'm passing it

Comment: are you passing this? `smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: Yes i'm posting String host = "smtp.gmail.com"; prop.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

Answer (score 0):

Having props.put("mail.smtp.host","173.194.78.108"); instead of 
 props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com"); solved the issue